# Creating TextField with using for loop

Tags: java, multithreading

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main extends JFrame {
    private JTextField noSeats,noAgent,maxWaitTime;
    public JPanel panel;
    private JButton btnCreate,btnBook;

    public Main () {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Book Application");
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.setSize(1000,1000);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700,700));

        noSeats = new JTextField("Number of Seats");
        noSeats.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                noSeats.setText("");
            }
        });

        noAgent = new JTextField("Number of Agent");
        noAgent.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                noAgent.setText("");
            }
        });

        maxWaitTime = new JTextField("Maximum waiting time");
        maxWaitTime.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                maxWaitTime.setText("");
            }
        });


        btnCreate = new JButton("Create Seats");
        btnCreate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                int seatsNumber = Integer.parseInt(noSeats.getText());
                int waitingTime = Integer.parseInt(maxWaitTime.getText());
                TestProduceThread t1 = new TestProduceThread(seatsNumber, waitingTime);


            }
        });

        btnBook = new JButton("Book");


        frame.getContentPane().add(noSeats);
        frame.getContentPane().add(noAgent);
        frame.getContentPane().add(maxWaitTime);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnCreate);
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnBook);

        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public synchronized void showThread (int number) {
        JTextField txtField;

        for (int i=0; i<number; i++) {
            txtField=new JTextField("Not Booked");
            panel.add(txtField);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

}
```

I want to create TextField with using foor loop and show in the frame but when ı run my application ıt opens multiscreen which I assign number of seats.How can I solve this problem?...............................................
...............................................
.........................................
.
.
..
.
.
.

Comment: Could you share what attempts you made to resolve this?

Comment: Where do you call `showThread()`?  What TestProduceThread do ?

Comment: import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TestProduceThread {
 private int waitingTime;
 private ExecutorService myPool;
 
 public TestProduceThread(int number,int waitingTime) {
  myPool=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(number);
  this.waitingTime = waitingTime;
  
  for(int i=0; i<number; i++) {
   myPool.execute(new ProduceThread(waitingTime,number));
  }
 }
 

}

Comment: public class ProduceThread implements Runnable{
 private int waitingTime,number;
 
 public ProduceThread(int waitingTime,int number) {
  // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
  this.waitingTime=waitingTime;
  this.number = number;
 }
 @Override
 public void run() {
  Main main = new Main();
  try {
   main.showThread(number);
   Thread.currentThread().sleep(waitingTime);
   
  }
  catch (InterruptedException  e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
  }
 
  
 }

}